# A function that takes string parameter and returns integer pointer

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, int

I am wondering,How to write a function in c that return *int* pointer for any *string* input

The below function is my attempt to solve the requirment

```
int* methodname(char* param)
{
  int *a;
  int b=3;
  a=&b;
  return a; 
}
```

Please correct me for any mistakes.

Comment: Don't return a pointer to local automatic variable. Better return `int` itself.

Comment: You're getting a dangling pointer as you are returning a pointer to a variable which is local to your function.

Comment: What exactly is your confusion?

Comment: You are returning a pointer to a variable that doesn't exist outside the function.

Comment: But I am getting confused with function pointer available in c. what is this line?

Comment: I have to return a integer pointer from method how to declare and define the method without getting dangling pointer ? Please help

Comment: Why do you need to return an `int`pointer ? You could return an `int`. Tell us more abour your program and what you intend to do. Maybe it's an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: `int` pointer to what? What are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: why function pointer came here :O

Comment: Do you want to return an array? Can you edit the question and add more details? For example: example input and output?

Comment: This was a question asked in a interview for me.. the method should return int pointer and take string ...I have to show how I declare and define it.

Comment: There has to be some relation between the `string` and the `int` pointer. Else its a very simple and vague question.

Comment: They just wanted to know if I have syntax level knowledge that's it .. I just want a proper declaration and definition

Comment: From the syntax point-of-view for the declaration your answer is correct. But the implementation/definition does not make sense.

Comment: Syntax is correct, but even then, it is invoking UB.

Comment: returning local address is undefined. use dynamic allocation and return that pointer.

Comment: Can anybody give me a code snippet that doesn't leave dangling pointer with method definition ?

Comment: @NaveenKumar People here spend enough of their valuable time leaving the above comments. Please read them yourself, and come up with the snippet. Nobody is here to write your code for you. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: @HyperZ -" You're getting a dangling pointer as you are returning a pointer to a variable which is local to your function " if the memory allocated locally is not free ...as far as I know it would lead to memory leak..not dangling pointer ! Plz correct me If I am wrong !

Comment: @NaveenKumar No it is not a memory leak. A memory leak is if you would have allocated an object locally and not deallocate it **before** going out of scope. Then as you forgot to deallocate it you can not do it anymore, hence that memory got wasted for always (i.e. a memory leak). Here what you have is a **pointer** to an adress in memory (`&b`), however after going out of scope it is pointing to garbage (i.e. it is a dangling pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Returning local address is undefined**, refer below code.

```
int* methodname(char* param)
{
  int *p = malloc(5*sizeof(int));
  . . .
  return p; 
}
```

Your declaration is ok but definition makes no sense, if any interviewer asked such kind of question their main intention is to check your programming skills, but your definition will not impress him, just write rough body(mainly concentrate on syntax, how you are returning and no undefined behavior) instead of implementing useless code.

Answer (score 3):

Within the definition of the question, which places no functionality on the function, the following would be a proper implementation without mallocs or undefined behavior:

```
int* methodname(char* param)
{
    return ((int *)param);  // just return the param as a pointer to int
}
```

Comment: any possibility for dangling pointer or memory leak ?

Comment: Well, I leave that to you as homework. Shouldn't be be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you asked. This code takes in a `char*` (char pointer), and returns a `int*` (pointer to int).

```
int* methodname(char* param)
{
    int* b = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *b = 3;
    return b; 
}
```

**NOTE**

The difference between your code and this one is, your code was returning `int` pointer to a local variable. The local variable will be destroyed after the function exits. In this example, the variable is allocated through `malloc()`. The memory allocated through `malloc()` is retained between function calls.

**I would suggest going through scope rules in C.**

**Edit**

There is nothing called `string*` in C. An array of `char`s with a terminating `'\0'` (`NUL`) is treated as a `string`.

Since the memory for the `int` is allocated by `malloc()`, it has to be freed to avoid any memory leaks. This can be done when the memory is not needed anymore.

Comment: allocated memory is not freed ? so memory leak possibility ?

Comment: @alk edited. Any better suggestion, you are welcome to edit. :)

Comment: the memory can be freed outside the method huh ? to the variable which the method is assigned

Comment: @alk its not always an "array of `char`s". I mean, its not called array when memory is allocated using `malloc()`

Comment: It is *always* an array. A C-"string" is a `0`-terminated `char`-array. How the array had been allocated is a different story though.

Comment: @alk It can be accessed as an array. But can it be called an array?

Comment: Please see my updated comment above.

Comment: Adding up to my pre-previous comment: "*How the array had been allocated ...*" and how it is accessed "*... is a different story, though.*"